# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in ... : eval()'d code on line 1

Tags: php, eval, template-engine

First of all, thank you for read my first stackoverflow question!!!

I have the code below:

```
eval('return ('.$statement.');')
```

I'm creating a template engine for study purposes, so, i need that code for some conditional actions on my views.

The objective of this code is execute a statement and return the logical result.

Suppose `$statement = '1 == 1';` this return true,

but, if i put `$statement = 'cookie()->has('name');'` this gives the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in
>   /var/www/html/exemplo.com/core/Instead/src/TemplateEngines/TemplateEngine.php(96)
>   : eval()'d code on line 1

Note that the cookie function already exists and is accessible globally, and return 1, only 1.

Any idea?? Solutions? Thanks Again.

Comment: This line of code is syntactically wrong:

`$statement = 'cookie()->has('name');`

It should be:

`$statement = 'cookie()->has("name");';`

Comment: You can not have put `$statement = 'cookie()->has('name');` anywhere, because that would cause a syntax error in itself already. And it makes little sense that you would get an error message complaining about an ampersand, if that is nowhere to be found in your code.

Comment: Sorry guys, the sintax error was my fault, the real code it's this: 'cookie()->has("name");';.

Comment: And this keep throwing the same error.

Comment: Gábor Nádai, even chaning with your code, this till showing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange, but for some reason, `$tatement = filter_var($statement, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` is causing the error, after replace this function to strip_tags the error is gone.